# avoid warning when using strictNullChecks in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

When I have a variable like:

`let object: {val1: string, val2: string} | null = null"`

and then use this somewhere:

```
function method() {

  if (object === null { return null }
  
  return object.val1 // warning as object can be null

}
```

Are there any ways that I can hide this warning here except writing `object?.val1`?

Something like Swift's `if let`, `guard let` statement would be good

Thank you !

Comment: How would the first line even compile? `object` is either an object with two string properties or null. How would you be able to assign a  simple string to it?

Comment: But, yes typically those checks work fine. One situation, where they don't work is, if there is some async code between the check and the referencing later on.

Comment: Assuming all the errors are fixed, then there is no warning: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBA9gRgViAxmAXBA3gNwIbAIxoDOYATgJYB2A5gDQQ7ABMRplVAvhAD4QUCuwYBAC8GergIQARMXLUpdBs2nYKUMAAsQJCLLZT2AWABQJgGZ8KyMlAoQAtuA1QAJgAoAlBhMmIEMmYQbrAIyCLCovyCXugQJOB8JHZRQkbGfr5xCUnQ8EhgAHQMeBAA9KUQAO7YSWwQ2IS5oZCIqhAwILwCwCZpQA)